# how to convert const Uint8* to Uint8*

Tags: c++, sdl

I think it is pretty self explanatory. I need to be able to convert a `const Uint8 *` to a `Uint8 *`. I have tried simply just put a `const Uint8 *` into `const Uint8 *` and using `static_cast`. however, every time it gave me this error:

```
error: 
  assigning to 'Uint8 *' (aka 'unsigned char *') from incompatible type
  'const Uint8 *' (aka 'const unsigned char *')
keyboardstate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
```

Anybody know how I can convert it successfully?

Comment: Use `const_cast`...

Comment: Why do you want to cast a immutable thing into a mutable thing in the first place? That looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @KamilCuk `const_cast` is dangerous though. If the object was not originally non-const, then casting away const is Undefined Behaviour if you modify the object.

Comment: @JesperJuhl that is not correct. Only if the object is actually modified it is UB. `const_cast` is particular important when working with libraries which are not const-aware.

Comment: I have to agree after implementing the const_cast solution the problem was fixed. plus the whole event system of my game was fixed with it. so I say that was one hell of a fix as I can now go throughout my day now knowing that my game is working how it should be.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann: The comment you're replying to says "... if you modify the object". Perhaps it was edited after your reply?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, the if-part was missing in the original comment

Comment: @Mikah `SDL_GetKeyboardState()` returns a `const Uint8*`.  Why is your `keyboardstate` variable declared as `Uint8*` instead of `const Uint8*` to begin with? Do you ever make modifications of the data pointed to by `keyboardstate`?  You shouldn't be, since the data is read-only, so `keyboardstate` should be a pointer to `const` data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the keyboard state variable is modified once every frame. so yes

Comment: @Mikah the variable itself, not the data it points at, correct? You need to understand the difference between a "non-const pointer to const data" (what `SDL_GetKeyboardState()` returns) vs a "const pointer to (const) data" (what you may be thinking of). They are NOT the same thing. It is valid to change a non-const pointer at will to point at new data, but you can't change the data it points at if the data is const. You can freely re-assign your `keyboardstate` variable as long as it is a no-const pointer, even if it is pointing at const data. The position of `const` in a declaration matters!

Comment: `const Uint8 *` vs `Uint8 * const` vs `const Uint8 * const` are all different types with different restrictions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`const_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) for this, e.g:

```
Uint8* foo = const_cast<Uint8*>(bar);
```

However: Are you sure that you are really doing the correct thing? Please verify that you don't modify the underlying value after removing constness as this  is undefined behaviour.

> [ Note: Depending on the type of the object, a write operation through the pointer, lvalue or pointer to data member resulting from a const_­cast that casts away a const-qualifier may produce undefined behavior ([dcl.type.cv]). — end note ]
>   [expr.const.cast.6]

Comment: thank you that worked